# escape behavior change

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, all,

on my robot, the escape behaviour in move_base navigation stack is too 'fierce'.
the rotation is much too fast.

how can I change it?

rgds

Ray

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188300/escape-behavior-change/) by [dreamcase](https://answers.ros.org/users/18446/dreamcase/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2014-07-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dreamcase](https://answers.ros.org/users/18446/dreamcase/) on 2014-07-30**:
Or, is there a way to inhibit the rotatory recovery behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The parameters for configuring the recovery behaviors are listed here: http://wiki.ros.org/rotate_recovery#TrajectoryPlannerROS_Parameters

You can remove the recovery behaviors by configuring the recovery_behaviors parameter. http://wiki.ros.org/move_base#Parameters

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2014-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dreamcase](https://answers.ros.org/users/18446/dreamcase/) on 2014-07-30**:
thanks David,
are they both set in base_local_planner_params.yaml? under "TrajectoryPlannerROS"

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-07-30**:
Probably. I don't know what your exact configuration is, but you can set them there. If you want them to be different than your normal path planning parameters, you have to set them somewhere else under the rotate_recovery namespace.